# OneDrive API browser C#

Tags: c#, api, onedrive

okay so I have decided to integrate onedrive capablities into my project, I have followed the instructions listed here:
https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sample-apibrowser-dotnet

I have set up the variables that were required to be set up, updated all the nuget libraries, registered the app and set the required permissions for reading and writing ect.

```
private const string AadClientId = "6b18d325-####-####-####-##########b0";
private const string AadReturnUrl = "http://localhost:44313";
private const string MsaClientId = "6b18d325-####-####-####-##########b0";
```

everything seems to be working up to the final login point. The project compiles and I click on "sign into aad"
I know this part is correct as the login page appears with my registered applications title above the login box.
the details get entered correctly and it informs you that it is logging in redirecting you and continues to a blank page with the header "continue", everything seems to be set right and going on track but then it hits a snag and returns an message box "Authentication failed", with the detailed exception stating: 
AADSTS50001: The application named http://localhost:44313 was not found in the tenant named 9188040d-####-####-####-##########ad.  This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant.  You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

Ive read up that I may need to do some things in AzureAD but im not sure, never done anything with one drive before so any assistance in helping me solve this would be great!

Thanks Guys appreciate it! 
Regards
James

Answer (score 1):

Registering an app on the Microsoft registration portal gives it access to the consumer version of OneDrive (in the demo, you access it by "Sign in to MSA") - that one should work for you, unless you've also set the MsaReturnUrl to be `localhost` (in which case, change it to the one originally in the sample). You'll be able to log in with your Live ID and access your OneDrive data.

The business version uses an Azure Active Directory you set up yourself, on Azure. Once you have one, that's where you'll be registering your application, adding users, and accessing the ClientId you'll eventually need to put into the code.

This is probably out of scope for this question - if you simply want to use personal OneDrive accounts, then use the `MsaAuthenticationProvider` and don't worry about those `Aad...` properties and the `AdalAuthenticationProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. it create application and secret in Azure portal with few clicks. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start

Please select the type of application that you want to create.
Next click is automated to create application, other things in azure portal on behalf of us.

```
 IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
       .Create(ClientId)
       .WithTenantId(TenantID)
       .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
       .Build();

        ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new **ClientCredentialProvider**(confidentialClientApplication);
        GraphServiceClient _graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
```

please change the auth provider accordingly. the current one is for authenticating application identity(with secret generate in Azure against application).